# No module named 'settings_general' when module exists

Tags: python, django, windows, conda, cmder

When I run manage.py in my terminal, I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_general'`. But, this module does exist in the project in a subfolder. I've ran this manage.py many times, but on mac. And now that the pandemic is occurring I am working from home and am working on a PC with Windows 10. I am using cmder for my terminal and conda for my virtual environment. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is worked on with a team and there should not be changes made to the file hierarchy or the contents of the file.

Here's my traceback for running "python manage.py migrate":

```
C:\Users\user\work\urec (master -> origin)
(urec) λ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 63, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 9, in check_database_backends
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 222, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\techops_work\urec\urec\settings.py", line 1, in <module>
    from settings_general import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_general'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\techops_work\urec\urec\settings.py", line 1, in <module>
    from settings_general import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_general'
```

This is the contents of the project:

```
(urec) λ ls
AUTHORS        fabfiles/    lostfound/  Procfile                      templates/    util/
client_side/   facilities/  manage.py*  README.md                     test.py
data/          fitness/     members/    requirements.txt              to-vagrant/
eventwaivers/  hr/          out.pdf     requirements_development.txt  urec/
fabfile.py     incidents/   partcount/  swipe/                        urec_crontab
```

and the contents of the subfolder where settings_general is located:

```
(urec) λ ls
__init__.py   settings.py              settings_general.py     settings_test.py     urls.py
__pycache__/  settings_development.py  settings_production.py  settings_testing.py  wsgi.py
```

Comment: It's a file in the same directory, not a module, so you should do `from .settings_general import *` or `from urec.settings_general import *`.

Comment: Your project path (the location of *manage.py* since that's what you're running) is the root for searching for modules, so to import any module, you need to base it on the project path or make it *relative* to the current file, which you do by prepending the `.`.

Comment: ah right, so normally on mac I'd use the command ```./manage.py migrate``` but when I do that in cmder I get an error that ```'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```. I tried ```python ./manage.py migrate``` and got the same ModuleNotFoundError as before. So do you have a suggestion on how to do this? Also, thank you for your help. I've only worked on mac and am new to running projects locally on Windows and am struggling a bit to figure things out.

Comment: but this can't work on mac either, you need to change the *settings.py* import command.

Comment: the only way this could work is if you add the *urec* folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: Why is Conda tagged? Is `urec` also the name of a Conda environment? Currently, your trace is showing that a system-level Python is taking priority on your PATH - not good for using Conda.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in *settings.py*:

```
from settings_general import *
```

The local directory is the location of *manage.py*, since that is the current script you're running. So when python searches for modules, it looks first for modules *relative to the root of your project* (after which it will look in `sys.path` which are paths to built-in packages and `pip` packages). In your case, `urec.settings_general` would work. `settings_general` cannot work, since it's not on the same path as *manage.py*.

Otherwise, you can use *relative* paths to modules, in which case you need to explicitly add a dot: `.settings_general`.

So: change the line to either

```
from .settings_general import *
```

of

```
from urec.settings_general import *
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The problem ended up being the python version my virtualenv was using

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the wrong version of python was being used. I changed the version from 3.x to 2.7 (correct version used in project) and the error was solved.